# Recommended way to create composite index in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-indexes

I have a oracle query structure like this:

```
SELECT <SOME_COLUMNS>
FROM A a
JOIN B b ON a.A_ID = b.A_ID
JOIN C c ON b.B_ID = c.B_ID
```

Ignore about WHERE clause.

Single column indexes are created on A_ID, B_ID and C_ID (C_ID is not used but it is the primary key in table C) already.

What is the best way to create other indexes out of these two methods for the above query?

**Method 01**

- Create single index for b.A_ID (Foreign Key)
- Create single index for c.B_ID (Foreign Key)

**Method 02**

- Create composite index for a.A_ID and b.A_ID
- Create composite index for b.B_ID and c.B_ID

Hope this will help others also.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause **is the key** for the index definition. Without `WHERE` you need no index as a `hash join` will be most probably  performed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create composite indexes **within a single table only**.

So as you proposed:

> Create composite index for a.A_ID and b.A_ID
>   Create composite index for b.B_ID and c.B_ID

It's not possible.

In your case single column indexes on columns a.A_ID, b.A_ID, c.A_ID will be just fine.

Comment: If multiple columns are used to join like `JOIN B b ON a.A_ID = b.A_ID AND b.XYZ = '123'` jist single column index enough or do I have to create composite index for `b.A_ID` and `b.XYZ`?

Comment: If most of your queries tends to always use both columns for joining or filtering in the WHERE clause, then yes, creating a composite index would make sense. Otherwise, it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Out of those two methods, it would be 01.

Method 02 won't work anyway; you can't create an index which contains columns from two tables (`a` and `b`).

Besides, depending on database version you use, foreign key columns *should be indexed*, otherwise locking might happen (and you'll wonder what's going on - lack of indexes is going on).

Comment: If multiple columns are used to join like `JOIN B b ON a.A_ID = b.A_ID AND b.XYZ = '123'` jist single column index enough or do I have to create composite index for `b.A_ID` and `b.XYZ`?

Comment: If you create a composite index, the optimizer will use both of them, or even just the leading column(s). Your best option is to try it; check explain plan and see what happens if there are indexes on separate columns, or if there's a composite index.